# What are the benefits of pure react native over expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I heard like the latest updates from Facebook to be available in the expo will take time when we implement Facebook login and get friends list. It will be great if someone lists all the pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

From Expo official site: [Why not Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo/)